# CK Editor 4 - Add script into .asp page

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

A friend of mine asked me a favor, help him to install CK Editor into SnitzForum (yeah old I know). Since I am not into asp lang. I have a problem since after putting into the head the CDN code I have to put below the  tag this code:

```
<script> CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );  </script>
```

So this is the part where the textarea is into the file post.asp:

```
<%
        end if
    end if
    Response.Write  "                      </font></td>" & vbNewLine & _
            "                    </tr>" & vbNewLine & _
            "                  </table>" & vbNewLine & _
            "                </font></td>" & vbNewLine & _
            "                <td bgColor=""" & strPopUpTableColor & """><textarea cols=""" & intCols & """ name=""editor1"" rows=""" & intRows & """ wrap=""VIRTUAL"" onselect=""storeCaret(this);"" onclick=""storeCaret(this);"" onkeyup=""storeCaret(this);"" onchange=""storeCaret(this);"">" & Trim(CleanCode(TxtMsg)) & "</textarea><br /></td>" & vbNewLine & _
            "             </tr>" & vbNewLine
            
end if
select case strRqMethod
    case "Reply", "ReplyQuote", "TopicQuote"
        Response.Write  "           <script language=""JavaScript"" type=""text/javascript"">document.PostTopic.Message.focus();</script>" & vbNewLine
end select
```

How can I add that script? Thanks :)

Edited Code:

```
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="inc_smilies.asp" -->
<%
        end if
    end if
    Response.Write  "                      </font></td>" & vbNewLine & _
            "                    </tr>" & vbNewLine & _
            "                  </table>" & vbNewLine & _
            "                </font></td>" & vbNewLine & _
            "                <td bgColor=""" & strPopUpTableColor & """><textarea cols=""" & intCols & """ name=""Message"" rows=""" & intRows & """ wrap=""VIRTUAL"" onselect=""storeCaret(this);"" onclick=""storeCaret(this);"" onkeyup=""storeCaret(this);"" onchange=""storeCaret(this);"">" & Trim(CleanCode(TxtMsg)) & "</textarea><br /></td>" & vbNewLine & _
            "              </tr>" & vbNewLine
            %>
 <script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      toolbar_mode: 'floating',
   });
  </script>
<%
end if
select case strRqMethod
    case "Reply", "ReplyQuote", "TopicQuote"
        Response.Write  "              <script language=""JavaScript"" type=""text/javascript"">document.PostTopic.Message.focus();</script>" & vbNewLine
end select
```

Comment: i would try really hard to avoid injecting the script, and put everything in a div, and use display none. I think the design which attempts to inject that html and text box is going to be messy, and problem filled.  I would layout that mark up in the designer, and use code behind to hide/show the edit area. CKedit runs a truckload of JavaScript against the page, and parses out a lot of things. And I think you have  difficult time injecting ckedit into the page as opposed to just placing it in the markup, and using code behind to hide/show the editor. it also much less messy code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so an working example with a text box could (would) be this:

```
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <div style="width:50%">

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="304px" Width="617px"
                TextMode="MultiLine"
                ClientIDMode="Static"
                ></asp:TextBox>

        </div>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace('TextBox1');
        </script>
```

And we now get this:

[image]

So, as noted, it probably better to hide/show the one div above, then trying to inject the above markup into the page. And the REASON why is that then in code behind, you want to be able to get the textbox by using

```
 TextBox1.text
```

So, by placing a plane jane text box (TextBox1) on the form, then code behind can use that text box. If you inject the markup, then code behind will have a much more difficult time using that markup and using TextBox1.Text to get the results of the markup in that text box.

So I don't see the need to use "code" to inject the above. As I noted, perhaps you need to hide/show this?

Then add a "ID" to the div like this:

```
        <div id="mycooleditor" runat="server" style="width:35%;display:none">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="304px" Width="617px"
                TextMode="MultiLine"
                ClientIDMode="Static"
                ></asp:TextBox>

        </div>
```

Now, in code behind,  to display the editor, we can go:

```
    mycooleditor.Style.Add("display", "normal")
```

So, unless you make a REALLY good case as to why we using code to inject the html into the web page as opposed just dropping in the markup as per above without any code (and saving world poverty's at the same time), then I see no reason to spend the time + effort writing code that does the same thing?

You can write code to inject, but I see no reason why when you can just drop in the markup anyway???

Comment: Well, I assume that you are using Visual Studio here. So while in the code editor, right click and choose View Designer. You be jumped over to the page markup, and you can use the visual designer, or you can display just the mark up, or you can display both.  it is possible that you might be using/working on a MVC project, and thus you don't get/have a visual designer - but one right click in code, and choosing visual designer will quite much let you know what you have here. As a general rule, you would be able to just cut+ paste the markup I had say right into your test web page.

Comment: Thanks but I need to know how to put this in that asp page. I can't copy the whole code here, is there any way to send here the post.asp file?

Comment: Well, if we can't do a simple cut + paste of the posted markup, then I think we have MUCH greater issues here?  Just cut + paste in the example markup into that page, or better yet create a new blank web page to play, to test, to try. Get that test page working first - you probably don't want to mess up a production page. But, as noted, if we can't simple paste in some markup, then we have much more problems here - this would suggest you can't use the markup editor in VS, and if one can't do that, then you need to learn that skill set first before attempting to modify ANY code or anything.

Comment: The thing is it is a very long mark up, how can I add a longer code here?

Comment: For a test, just cut + paste in what I had above - it not much markup. As I stated, you "might" be able to try and use that code to inject this, but it 100 x easier to just paste in the small amount of markup into that existing page. As I stated, might be good idea to just create a test page to see how this works, and then take the wee bit of markup we posted here and simple paste that into the existing page you have. That's quite much all you really need here. Some truckload of markup for us here helps no one. You just drop drop in a text box, and the one line script is all you going to do.

Comment: Okay I added it, but not even TinyMCE is not showing. Take a look, I edited the first post with my actual code.

Comment: I would first create a blank new test page - drop in the sample markup I posted - make sure that works first. If that works, then you should be able to move + copy that markup into the real production page. (that way you can test/play and not mess up that existing page). Get that working. It always hard to mess/change an existing page. Once that works? Then move markup to your existing page (I don't see any existing markup posted from that existing page - only your code behind part???).

Comment: Classic ASP is not ASP.Net the `<asp:` syntax is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Overworked.  Put the tinymce files in their own folder (titled "tinyMCE") below the forum root. In the file "inc_header.asp", look for this code (appx lines 240-242):

```
'## START - REMOVAL, MODIFICATION OR CIRCUMVENTING THIS CODE WILL VIOLATE THE SNITZ FORUMS 2000 LICENSE AGREEMENT
Response.Write  "<meta name=""copyright"" content=""This Forum code is Copyright (C) 2000-09 Michael Anderson, Pierre Gorissen, Huw Reddick and Richard Kinser, Non-Forum Related code is Copyright (C) " & strCopyright & """>" & vbNewline
'## END   - REMOVAL, MODIFICATION OR CIRCUMVENTING THIS CODE WILL VIOLATE THE SNITZ FORUMS 2000 LICENSE AGREEMENT
```

Below that bit, insert this:

```
If strScriptName = "post.asp" Then
    Response.Write "        <script src=""./tinyMCE/tinymce.js""></script>" & vbNewLine & _
        "           <script language=""Javascript"">tinymce.init ({" & vbNewLine & _
        "               selector:'textarea'," & vbNewLine & _
        "               theme:'modern'," & vbNewLine & _
        "               browser_spellcheck:'true'," & vbNewLine & _
        "               plugins:['advlist anchor autolink charmap code contextmenu directionality emoticons fullscreen hr insertdatetime image link lists media nonbreaking paste print preview pagebreak save searchreplace table template textcolor visualblocks visualchars wordcount']," & vbNewLine & _
        "               content_css:'css/combined-min.css'," & vbNewLine & _
        "               toolbar:'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons'," & vbNewLine & _
        "       });</script>" & vbNewLine
End If
```

That will take over all instances of the text area in "post.asp".  If you want to use it throughout the forum for text areas, remove the If/End If lines.